# Managing multiple progressive numbers in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this to manage the generation of the receipt's progressive number in a multiuser app:

```
ID                 | Int(11) Auto increment, primary
Progressive_number | Int(11)
External_ID        | Int(11)
```

The progressive must be relative to the External_ID quee, with External_ID rappresenting a reference to the primary id of an external table.
For example:

```
ID | Prog | ExtID
1  | 1    | 1
2  | 2    | 1
3  | 1    | 2
4  | 3    | 1
5  | 4    | 1
6  | 2    | 2
```

Thus far is easy, but the problem is that the progressive number must be unique in the quee, and that many users can generate it at the same moment

My first tought was to read the last Progressive and then insert the increment, like this:

```
SELECT MAX(Progressive_number) FROM table WHERE External_id = 2
```

But from some stress test, before I execute the successive INSERT query, some other can read the same value and then execute the same INSERT, so I end up with two receipts with the same progressive number

I've tried with a nested query

```
INSERT INTO table (Progressive_number, External_ID) 
VALUES(
    (SELECT MAX(Progressive_number) FROM table WHERE External_id = 2) + 1, 
1)
```

I have many less duplicates, but one duplicate is too much for this kind of app.

There's a way to offload completely the generation to the mysql server to be sure that any number is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried locking the tables during the read-write operation?

```
LOCK TABLES table WRITE;
INSERT INTO table (Progressive_number, External_ID) 
VALUES(
    (SELECT MAX(Progressive_number) FROM table WHERE External_id = 2) + 1, 
1)
;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

(See also the doc on LOCK TABLES: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html)

Comment: I've not tried this time because I remember that is not a fully reliable method, is it?

Comment: I haven't heard that it's not fully reliable. However, one reason it might not be in more popular use is that it locks the whole table (for writing) and it requires a LOCK privilege (not just READ and WRITE).  It's still what I would try.

Comment: I will try it, but can see the latencie problems down the road when all the accounts (in the thousand range) will try to generate the progressive :S

Comment: @Arth's response looks better.

Comment: They are equally valid in my opinion, `LOCK`ing the whole table for write is more data secure in a complicated system where `INSERT` performance isn't a huge issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do the following in a transaction for each `INSERT` :

Get a named lock, should be quicker than a table lock:

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('table_insert_external_id_2', 30);
```

Where 'table_insert_external_id_2' is a specific named lock and 30 is the timeout in seconds; and back out if the select returns 0.

Perform the insert:

```
INSERT INTO table (Progressive_number, External_ID) 
VALUES((SELECT MAX(Progressive_number) FROM table WHERE External_id=2)+1,1)
```

Release the named lock:

```
SELECT RELEASE_LOCK('table_insert_external_id_2');
```

That way other processes can interact with the table as normal.

[**MORE INFO**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html)

Comment: I must still fully understand the differenxe, but will try it :)

Comment: @Fehu It creates an artificial named lock, only locking processes that call GET_LOCK('table_insert', x) and doesn't lock the table.

Comment: @Fehu I have updated the answer to show that you can name each lock to a specific external id for each insert allowing more fluid access.